# How to avoid an error running a simple yaml header?

Tags: header, r-markdown

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong to have a header in my html rmarkdown output? I have searched a lot and everywhere there is the below code as solution. But I get the error below.

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author Name"
output:
  html_document:
   include:
      before_body: header.html
      after_body: footer.html
---
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning a simple key at line 7, column 3 could not find expected ':' at line 8, column 3
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of trial and error and search I found that the problem was the indentation of `include:`. So indentation matters in YAML headers!

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author Name"
output:
  html_document:
    include:
      before_body: header.html
      after_body: footer.html
---
```